# Putting values from MySql query onto form in vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to extract values from my MySql table and put them onto a form in VB. I want the user to have a list of all the movies he/she is currently renting. I know the MySql statement works so its just a problem with actually getting at the values. Any help would be great! I have the following code:

```
 Private Sub Form9_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     MyBase.Load
    NoMovies.Visible = False
    Dim query As String
    Dim ans As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    'another query and a two table join'
    query = "SELECT movie_name from movie2 Where movie_id=(SELECT movie_id from rental where client_username='" & currentUser & "' AND start_date<='" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND return_date>='" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "')"
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
          "server=mysql.scss.tcd.ie;userid=murpha83;password=gh8ht6789;database=murpha83_db"
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(Command)
    da.Fill(ds, "Subject_Detail")
    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
    If Reader.HasRows = True Then
    'Think I Should extract the values and put them on the form here '


    Else
        NoMovies.Visible = True
    End If
    MysqlConn.Close()
    Reader.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Alan.

Comment: Dont concat strings to make SQL, use parameters; no need to convert dates to strings. No need for a DataReader and a DataTable.  The data is in the DT, fish it out and put it on the form or use a BindingSource; and some of those data provider objects should be disposed.

Comment: How do i go about fishing the data out of the DT and put it on the form? Thanks Plutonix

Comment: Well, the query looks like it returns multiple rows, so using a DGV: `myDGV.DataSource = ds("Subject_Detail")`.  No need for a DataSet that you just throw away either.  I'd use a DataView probably, so you can change the row filter without having to query the DB again (and again and again).  The DB provider objects are very powerful and can do **much** more than just exec SQL.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too familiar at using VB, how do I use the DataView and how do i get the results of my query into ds?

Comment: This is not a tutorial site, but have you *looked* at your code?  `da.Fill(ds, "Subject_Detail")` fills a table named "Subject_Detail" in the dataset named `ds`.  That table has the results.